# Making iCloud documents local after iCloud is disabled by the user

Tags: ios, icloud

As noted by the Document-Based App Programming Guide, "When the user changes the preference, the application should move all document files in the application sandbox to iCloud or move all files in the other direction, depending on the nature of the change.”

But `NSMetaDataQuery` does not run when iCloud is disabled, so how can I get the URLs of the user's iCloud documents so I can transfer each to the local directory?

Comment: Presumably when the user changes the preference you have a list left over from the last metadata query callback, right? (That's what my app does)

Answer (score 0):

This was under the assumption the docs meant in the iCloud Drive switch. Instead they mean an option in the app's preferences that you add yourself.